# How to store Objects (instructions) in a list and invoke it?

Tags: java, methods, invoke

Suppose if i want to  add Objects (instructions) in list and invoke in sequence from that list?
e.g

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(System.out.println("1"))
    list.add(System.out.println("2"))
    list.add(System.out.println("3"))

    try{
        for(Object i : list){
        i.invoke()   //....like this i want to invoke each syso
       }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is definitely not Java (maybe you meant JavaScript?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store "instructions" in a list. All you can store is Objects. But objects have methods, and you can call these methods:

```
List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(() -> System.out.println("1"));
list.add(() -> System.out.println("2"));
list.add(() -> System.out.println("3"));

for (Runnable r : list) {
    r.run();
}
```

The above is using lambdas, available since Java 8. But you could use anonymous classes in previous versions instead:

```
List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("1");
    }
});
list.add(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("2");
    }
});
list.add(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        System.out.println("3");
    }
});   

for (Runnable r : list) {
    r.run();
}
```

Or you could define your own Printer class:

```
public class Printer {
    private final String toPrint;

    public Printer(String toPrint) {
        this.toPrint = toPrint;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(toPrint);
    }
}


List<Printer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Printer("1"));
list.add(new Printer("2"));
list.add(new Printer("3"));

for (Printer p : list) {
    p.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interface and then provide concrete methods for your steps :

```
public interface Action {

    void doStuff();

}
```

Invoking class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Action> list = new ArrayList<Action>();
        list.add(new Action() {

            @Override
            public void doStuff() {
                //Custom code for the step
            }
        });
        //Invoke

        for(Action action : list) {
            action.doStuff();
        }
    }
```